# Is the following optimization problem convex? something like a cosine similarity measure.

Tags: convex-optimization

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{W}{\text{minimize}} & - \displaystyle\sum_{t=1}^T \frac{W^\top A a_t}{\| W^\top A \|_2 \| a_t \|_2}\\ \text{subject to} & \sum_{t=1}^T w_t =1\\ & w_t \geq 0  \text { for } t \in T\end{array}$$

where $W = [w_1, w_2,\dots, w_T]^\top \in \Bbb R^{T \times 1}$, $A = [a_1, a_2,..., a_T] \in \Bbb R^{T \times n}$, $a_t \in \Bbb R^{n\times 1}$.

It is intuitive that the problem is convex, and I have tied to prove that it is convex by using the definition of convex function. However, I have failed.

Can I have your help? Is the problem convex? If it is, is there any hint of the proof?

Comment: The domain is convex and the objective function is a finite sum of affine transforms. Right?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the domain is convex. But，the objective function is not an  affine transforms, for  there is a normalization term (denominator). So, the convexity is difficult to determine.

Comment: Think about $a^Tx$ where both norms of a and x are 1

Comment: Thank you. However, in the problem, we cannot assume that the  norm of  $\parallel W^T A\parallel_2 = 1$ .

Comment: WtA/||wtA|| has norm 1

Comment: Why are some vectors uppercase and others lowercase?